# Radio button javascript validation

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 radio buttons A & B. the B button also have one text field.

By default next button is hidden and it should appear in the following cases

1. If user click button A
2. User click button B and enter text in the textfield

I try this:

## JavaScript

```
window.onload=function(){
   document.getElementById("next").style.display='none';
} 

function shownext(){
  var A = document.getElementById('A').value;
  var B = document.getElementById('B').value;
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  if(A != "" || (B != "" && name != "")){
  document.getElementById("next").style.display='block';
     return false;
  }
  if(A == "" && B == "" && name == ""){
  document.getElementById("next").style.display='none';
     return false;
  }
}
```

## HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="A" id="A" value="A" onClick="shownext();"/>
<input type="radio" name="A" id="B" value="B" onClick="shownext();"/>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" onKeyDown="shownext();" onKeyUp="shownext();"/>

<a href="#q2" id="next"><img src="next.png"/></a>
```

Comment: Switch to jQuery? Also, you *would like* to have same name for both `radio buttons`.

Comment: @BackinaFlash ya by mistake I give different names, I want to fix this code instead of switching to jQuery

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis in first `if` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your first `if` statement — you're opening more parentheses than you're closing.

Your radio buttons *always* have a `value`, so you cannot check their state by just inspecting the value. You need to inspect their `checked` property instead.

You also don't need both `if`s, an `else` to the first `if` would be more appropriate, since you basically have only two possible outcomes (show the "next" button or hide it).

Here is a [working demo of the fixed code](http://jsbin.com/onawem/1/edit).